# Writing multiple images with OpenCv2 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I got a Data set which full of images. My aim is converting this images to gray scale. I can easily do this with one image but I need to do whit multiple images. Here is my code;

```
import cv2
import glob

path = "/path/*.jpg"

for file in glob.glob(path):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
    cv2.imwrite('/path/cat' + '_gray.jpg', gray)
```

When I run this script, it's only convert a single image but my aim is converting the all images in the path. I'm really beginer on image processing and OpenCv2 module. Thanks already now for your helps.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070242/converting-images-to-csv-file-in-python/49070833#49070833) might help. Get a list of all your files first, then do your colour conversion (which you're doing correctly as far as I can tell).

Comment: greate! I think it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'/path/cat' + '_gray.jpg'` always gives you `/path/cat_gray.jpg`, regardless of the input filename.

You probably want to use some part of the original file name there, which you can find using the functions in the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module.

For example:

```
import cv2
import glob
import os.path

path = "/path/*.jpg"

for file in glob.glob(path):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
    basename = os.path.basename(file)  # e.g. MyPhoto.jpg
    name = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]  # e.g. MyPhoto
    cv2.imwrite('/path/' + name + '_gray.jpg', gray)
```